# Conformal Mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

The function,
$$u(x,0) =  \begin{cases} 0,   |x|\ge1;\\
           1 & |x|<1 \end{cases} $$
when mapped by
 the function
$$F(z) = \log \frac{1-z}{1+z} = k+il$$

turns out to be $1$ when $l=\pi$ and $0 $ when $l=0$ . How? Could anyone please explain me this ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking about $F(u)$?